# Existence of a Fibonacci number divisible by $10^n$

Tags: divisibility, pigeonhole-principle

> Prove that for any given positive integer $n$,there exists a Fibonacci  number divisible by $10^n$.

Another application of pigeon hole principle,and the main problem is finding the holes and pigeons.If we consider $10^n+1$ consecutive Fibonacci numbers,we can NOT  claim that one of them is certainly divisible by $10^n$,but of course two of them have equal remainders mod $10^n$.
I DO KNOW this question has an elementary solution using pigeon hole principle,although  the older question asked for $n=2014$ has received many advanced solutions.

Comment: Not exactly, all you can claim is that at least two of them have the same value mod $10^n$.  Theoretically, they could all have value $1\mod 10^n$.  This doesn't seem to be the case by the way the problem is stated, but you'll probably have to apply part of the Fibonacci recurrence to get this result.

Comment: @Mark So you mean the problem statement is not correct?!

Comment: I mean the solution you had written would apply to any list of numbers with $10^n$ elements, and the thing you want to prove is false for generic lists of this type.  You need to incorporate some properties of the Fibonacci numbers into your proof.

Answer (score 0):

Three hints:

1. Make your pigeonholes pairs of remainders module $10^n$.
2. If you know that $F_m=F_n \mod 10^n$ and $F_{m+1}=F_{n+1}\mod 10^n$ then you can work backwards in the sequence to show that $F_{m-1}=F_{n-1} \mod 10^n$.
3. Use the fact that $F_0=0$.